# Запрет стандартного поведения select на мобильном

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ios, select

Добрый день, можете пожалуйста подсказать как отключить стандартный вызов select панели на ios?

вот у меня есть кастомный select и мне нужно отключить стандартную select панель, пробовал

preventDefault() - не помогает

пытался отключить фокус blur() - не помогает

P.S. Кастомный select использую Select2[image]

Comment: Скажи пожалуйста это у тебя обычный select как в html или какой-то компонент из библиотеки? У меня просто наоборот не выходит так отобразить на ios, отображается выпадающим списком..

Comment: @КристинаВоронюк Использовал компонент из библиотеки Select2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот решение:

```
select {
visibility: hidden;
}
```